# nicematrix, LaTeX3 matrix naming and for loop

Tags: beamer, latex3, nicematrix

The following code fails. I am looking for some advice.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\NewDocumentCommand\drawstrike{ mmm } {  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        remember picture, 
        overlay
    ]
        \draw[
            very thick, 
            red, 
            opacity = 0.5
        ] 
        ([xshift=-3pt]this-#1-#2-#3.north west)
        --
        ([xshift=3pt]this-#1-#2-#3.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l_row_int
\int_new:N \l_col_int

\NewDocumentCommand\strikeme{ mmm } {
    \int_set:Nn \l_row_int { \int_div_truncate:nn {#3}{#2} }
    \int_set:Nn \l_col_int { \int_mod:nn {#3} {#2}}
    
    \int_compare:nNnTF \l_col_int = 0 {
        \int_set:Nn \l_col_int { #2 }
    } {
        \int_set:Nn \l_row_int { \l_row_int + 1}
    }

    \drawstrike{#1}{\int_use:N \l_row_int}{\int_use:N \l_col_int}
}

\seq_new:N \l_notprime_seq

\int_new:N \l_tested_int
\int_new:N \l_striked_int
\int_new:N \l_max_int

\NewDocumentCommand\eratosthenes{ O{#2}m }{   
    $\AutoNiceMatrix[
        hvlines, 
        columns - width = auto,
        name            = this-#1   % NOT SEEN FROM THE LOOP...
    ]{
        #2-#2
    }{
        \cellval{#2}{\arabic{iRow}}{\arabic{jCol}}
    }$
   
    \int_set:Nn \l_tested_int { 1 }
    \int_set:Nn \l_max_int { #2*#2 }
    
    \int_while_do:nn {
         \l_tested_int <= #1
    } {
        \int_compare:nNnTF \l_tested_int = 1 {
            \strikeme{#1}{#2}{1}
            \seq_put_left:Nn \l_notprime_seq 1
        } {
            \seq_if_in:NxF \l_notprime_seq {\int_use:N \l_tested_int} {
                \int_set:Nn \l_striked_int { 2*\l_tested_int }
                
                \int_while_do:nn {
                    \l_striked_int <= \l_max_int
                } {
                    \seq_if_in:NxF \l_notprime_seq {\int_use:N \l_striked_int} {
                        \strikeme{#1}{#2}{\int_use:N \l_striked_int}
                        \seq_put_left:Nx \l_notprime_seq {\int_use:N \l_striked_int}
                    }
    
                    \int_set:Nn \l_striked_int { \l_striked_int + \l_tested_int }         
                }
            }
        }
        
        \int_incr:N \l_tested_int
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\cellval{ mmm }{    
    \int_eval:n{#3 + #1*(#2 - 1)}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {0,...,4}{
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Étape \i}
        \begin{center}
            \eratosthenes[\i]{10}
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems to fail in article as well: `Package nicematrix Error: Duplicate name.`

Comment: Title edited. Ducks test too quickly.

Comment: @ projetmbc Quack :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UPDATE:

In the latest version of `nicematrix` (6.20a 2023-06-30), the value of the key `name` is expanded (in the TeX sens).

Hence, the output is as expected...

---

In the current version of `nicematrix` (v. 6.20 2023-06-04), the value of the key `name` of an environment or command of `nicematrix` (such as `\AutoNiceMatrix`) is not expanded (and stored as a `str` of L3). Therefore, all your arrays have the same name: `this-\i`.

Maybe it would be a good idea to change that behavior in the next version of `nicematrix`...

At this time, the workaround is to expand the optional argument of your command `\eratosthenes`. The best way is probably to use `\exp_args:Nx` in the command `\eratosthenes`, which requires an auxiliary function at the L3 level:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\eratosthenes{ O{#2}m }{   
  \exp_args:Nx \__projetmbc_eratosthenes:nn { #1 } { #2 }
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__projetmbc_eratosthenes:nn {
    $\AutoNiceMatrix[
        hvlines, 
        columns - width = auto,
.........
```

Here is the whole code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\NewDocumentCommand\drawstrike{ mmm } {%  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        remember picture, 
        overlay
    ]
        \draw[
            very thick, 
            red, 
            opacity = 0.5
        ] 
        ([xshift=-3pt]this-#1-#2-#3.north west)
        --
        ([xshift=3pt]this-#1-#2-#3.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l_row_int
\int_new:N \l_col_int

\NewDocumentCommand\strikeme{ mmm } {
    \int_set:Nn \l_row_int { \int_div_truncate:nn {#3}{#2} }
    \int_set:Nn \l_col_int { \int_mod:nn {#3} {#2}}
    
    \int_compare:nNnTF \l_col_int = 0 {
        \int_set:Nn \l_col_int { #2 }
    } {
        \int_set:Nn \l_row_int { \l_row_int + 1}
    }

    \drawstrike{#1}{\int_use:N \l_row_int}{\int_use:N \l_col_int}
}

\seq_new:N \l_notprime_seq

\int_new:N \l_tested_int
\int_new:N \l_striked_int
\int_new:N \l_max_int

\NewDocumentCommand\eratosthenes{ O{#2}m }{   
  \exp_args:Nx \__projetmbc_eratosthenes:nn { #1 } { #2 }
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__projetmbc_eratosthenes:nn {
    $\AutoNiceMatrix[
        hvlines, 
        columns - width = auto,
        name            = this-#1 
    ]{
        #2-#2
    }{
        \cellval{#2}{\arabic{iRow}}{\arabic{jCol}}
    }$
   
    \int_set:Nn \l_tested_int { 1 }
    \int_set:Nn \l_max_int { #2*#2 }
    
    \int_while_do:nn {
         \l_tested_int <= #1
    } {
        \int_compare:nNnTF \l_tested_int = 1 {
            \strikeme{#1}{#2}{1}
            \seq_put_left:Nn \l_notprime_seq 1
        } {
            \seq_if_in:NxF \l_notprime_seq {\int_use:N \l_tested_int} {
                \int_set:Nn \l_striked_int { 2*\l_tested_int }
                
                \int_while_do:nn {
                    \l_striked_int <= \l_max_int
                } {
                    \seq_if_in:NxF \l_notprime_seq {\int_use:N \l_striked_int} {
                        \strikeme{#1}{#2}{\int_use:N \l_striked_int}
                        \seq_put_left:Nx \l_notprime_seq {\int_use:N \l_striked_int}
                    }
    
                    \int_set:Nn \l_striked_int { \l_striked_int + \l_tested_int }         
                }
            }
        }
        
        \int_incr:N \l_tested_int
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\cellval{ mmm }{    
    \int_eval:n{#3 + #1*(#2 - 1)}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {0,...,4}{
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Étape \i}
        \begin{center}
            \eratosthenes[\i]{10}
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Some monkeys like to look at the finger rather at the moon...

Comment: Just a quick question. In the slides, the different tables are not aligned in the same way. Is this due to my code?

Comment: You have spurious spaces in your command `\drawstrike` (which is *not* between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `ExplSyntaxOff`). I have added two `%` in the code and it solves the problem.

Comment: *"Aïe !"* Thanks for pointing this....

Answer (score 4):

Use of the so ugly `\expandafter` does the job. Is there another way to do that?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\NewDocumentCommand\drawstrike{ mmm } {  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        remember picture, 
        overlay
    ]
        \draw[
            very thick, 
            red, 
            opacity = 0.5
        ] 
        ([xshift=-3pt]this-#1-#2-#3.north west)
        --
        ([xshift=3pt]this-#1-#2-#3.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l_row_int
\int_new:N \l_col_int

\NewDocumentCommand\strikeme{ mmm } {
    \int_set:Nn \l_row_int { \int_div_truncate:nn {#3}{#2} }
    \int_set:Nn \l_col_int { \int_mod:nn {#3} {#2}}
    
    \int_compare:nNnTF \l_col_int = 0 {
        \int_set:Nn \l_col_int { #2 }
    } {
        \int_set:Nn \l_row_int { \l_row_int + 1}
    }

    \drawstrike{#1}{\int_use:N \l_row_int}{\int_use:N \l_col_int}
}

\seq_new:N \l_notprime_seq

\int_new:N \l_tested_int
\int_new:N \l_striked_int
\int_new:N \l_max_int

\NewDocumentCommand\eratosthenes{ O{#2}m }{   
    $\AutoNiceMatrix[
        hvlines, 
        columns - width = auto,
        name            = this-#1
    ]{
        #2-#2
    }{
        \cellval{#2}{\arabic{iRow}}{\arabic{jCol}}
    }$
   
    \int_set:Nn \l_tested_int { 1 }
    \int_set:Nn \l_max_int { #2*#2 }
    
    \int_while_do:nn {
         \l_tested_int <= #1
    } {
        \int_compare:nNnTF \l_tested_int = 1 {
            \strikeme{#1}{#2}{1}
            \seq_put_left:Nn \l_notprime_seq 1
        } {
%           \int_show:N \l_tested_int
%           \seq_show:N \l_notprime_seq

            \seq_if_in:NxF \l_notprime_seq {\int_use:N \l_tested_int} {
                \int_set:Nn \l_striked_int { 2*\l_tested_int }
    
%               \int_show:N \l_striked_int
                
                \int_while_do:nn {
                    \l_striked_int <= \l_max_int
                } {
                    \seq_if_in:NxF \l_notprime_seq {\int_use:N \l_striked_int} {
                        \strikeme{#1}{#2}{\int_use:N \l_striked_int}
                        \seq_put_left:Nx \l_notprime_seq {\int_use:N \l_striked_int}
                    }
    
                    \int_set:Nn \l_striked_int { \l_striked_int + \l_tested_int }         
                }
            }
        }
        
        \int_incr:N \l_tested_int
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\cellval{ mmm }{    
    \int_eval:n{#3 + #1*(#2 - 1)}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {0,...,4}{
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Étape \i}
        \begin{center}
            \expandafter\eratosthenes\expandafter[\i]{10}
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```